# How to solve this issue? TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>

Tags: python, pandas

I get the following error:

> TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>

How can I solve this issue?

My code:

```
data = pd.read_table('views.txt', index_col=0)

data_cos = pd.read_table('data_cos.txt', index_col=0)

user_neighbor = pd.read_table('data_neighbor.txt', index_col=0)

scores = pd.DataFrame(data.columns, columns=['sum'])

prediction = pd.DataFrame(data.index, columns=['hotel'])

for user in range(1, len(data.index)+1): 
      
     if user % 10 == 1:
        print(user)
    for hotel in range(0, len(data.columns)):
        running_score = 0
        for nb in user_neighbor.loc[user]:
            running_score += (data_cos.loc[user, nb-1] * data.loc[nb, hotel])
        scores.loc[hotel, 'sum'] = running_score
    rec_list = scores.sort(columns=['sum'], ascending=False).index
    for rec in rec_list:
        viewed_list = activity.loc[activity['user'] == user]['hotel'].values
        if int(rec) not in viewed_list:
            prediction.loc[user]['hotel'] = rec
            break
prediction.to_csv('prediction.txt', sep='\t')
```